# NX Angular unit tests fail because of NullInjectorError

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, jestjs, nrwl-nx, nx-monorepo

I'm trying to use Angular Injection Tokens in my app, but it keeps causing my unit tests to fail.

Here is a repo that demonstrates the issue:

https://github.com/shadow1349/nx-filereplacementissue/tree/main

If you check out the main branch, run `npm install`, and then run `npx nx run test:test` You'll see the following error:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[ComponentsComponent])
[InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN -> InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN -> InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN!
```

Here's my injection token located here: https://github.com/shadow1349/nx-filereplacementissue/blob/main/shared/injection-tokens/src/index.ts

```js
export const TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<BehaviorSubject<string>>(
  'TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN'
);
```

My app config, located here: https://github.com/shadow1349/nx-filereplacementissue/blob/main/test/src/app/app.config.ts

```js
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './app.routes';
import { TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN } from '@test-filereplacements/injection-tokens';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(appRoutes),
    {
      provide: TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN,
      useValue: new BehaviorSubject<string>('Hello World'),
    },
  ],
};
```

Then I have a shared component that's imported into my App Component called ComponentsComponent, located here:

https://github.com/shadow1349/nx-filereplacementissue/blob/main/test/src/app/app.component.ts

and here:

https://github.com/shadow1349/nx-filereplacementissue/blob/main/shared/components/src/lib/components/components.component.ts

```js
// app component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NxWelcomeComponent } from './nx-welcome.component';
import { ComponentsComponent } from '@test-filereplacements/components';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NxWelcomeComponent, RouterModule, ComponentsComponent],
  selector: 'test-filereplacements-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {}

//components.component.ts
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN } from '@test-filereplacements/injection-tokens';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-filereplacements-components',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './components.component.html',
  styleUrl: './components.component.css',
})
export class ComponentsComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject(TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN) public testToken: BehaviorSubject<string>
  ) {
    console.log('testToken', this.testToken);
  }
}
```

This all works fine when you run `npx nx run test:serve --configuration=development` it will console log just fine.

Here's where you will run into the issue. If you run the test with Jest it will pass. However, when you run `npx nx run test:test` it fails with:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[ComponentsComponent])
[InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN -> InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN -> InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN!
```

I know the first question you're going to ask is if in app.component.ts do I have the provider for the injection token, yes I do. You can see it here:

https://github.com/shadow1349/nx-filereplacementissue/blob/main/test/src/app/app.component.spec.ts

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NxWelcomeComponent } from './nx-welcome.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN } from '@test-filereplacements/injection-tokens';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppComponent, NxWelcomeComponent, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN,
          useValue: new BehaviorSubject<string>('Hello World'),
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should exist', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Yet, it still thinks that the injection token doesn't exist. Does anyone know why?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit Test Angular Standalone Component, Overriding Provider not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77395557/unit-test-angular-standalone-component-overriding-provider-not-used)

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[ComponentsComponent])
[InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN -> InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN -> InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN!
```

The inject token is provided in the constructor of ComponentsComponent.ts

To fix this issue, you need to provide InjectionToken in your component :

Approach with customer provider: create your customer provider and can be called at the root and feature levels

```
export const provideToken = (value = 'TEST 123') => {
  const providers: Provider[] = [
    {
      provide: TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN,
      useValue: new BehaviorSubject<string>(value),
    }
  ];
  return providers;
};
```

ComponentsComponent with customer provider:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-filereplacements-components',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './components.component.html',
  styleUrl: './components.component.css',
  providers: [
    provideToken()
  ],
})
```

And app.config.ts

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(appRoutes),
    provideToken()
  ],
};
```

Comment: Hey @Alpine A110R, thanks for your answer! While this does indeed fix the tests, it breaks the functionality of the injection tokens. I want to be able to set the value of the injection token globally from the App Config and use that value everywhere. With this method, the global token is overridden by the provider defined in the component providers array.

Comment: I created a branch testing your fix as well if you want to have a look.

https://github.com/shadow1349/nx-filereplacementissue/blob/Alpine-A110R/test/src/app/app.config.ts



https://github.com/shadow1349/nx-filereplacementissue/blob/Alpine-A110R/shared/components/src/lib/components/components.component.ts

Comment: @SamRedmond you can create your customer provider, I have updated my answer ;)

Comment: Gotcha, that works, thank you! I did have one more question, which I realize I forgot to include in my original post. If I wanted to modify the value in app component like this https://github.com/shadow1349/nx-filereplacementissue/blob/Alpine-A110R/test/src/app/app.component.ts how can I get that to modify the variable when it hits components component?

Comment: I suspect that I'm starting to get into the, just use a state management library territory lol